# How to toggle between gallery-thumbnails and a specific slideshow-image on the same page?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, visibility, image-gallery

This is my first question, but I did read the guidelines. I hope you'll welcome me to the community with a straight answer.

I'm working on a gallery-website where JQuery is not a dependency. I'm trying to switch between a thumbnails-view of all pictures and a slideshow-view showing only one picture, namely, the one picture whose thumbnail I clicked on. Also, I want the thumbnails-view and the slideshow-view to be separate, one to not show when the other does, but I want to have them both on the same page, that is, not to have two separate pages one for each of them, and I don't want to use pop-ups for the switch. Furthermore, I want to switch back to thumbnails-view when clicking on the slideshow-view picture, and also, to switch between previous and next picture when clicking on the previous and next sides/buttons surrounding the picture. One example where this is achieved as I want it is in Milo:

https://madebyminimal.com/demo/milo/

I spent most of yesterday trying out a lot of functions in Javascript, playing around with the opacity, visibility and display CSS features, but whatever I do, the specific picture whose thumbnail I clicked on does not show, and it seems like Javascript does not respond to my clicking anything in the thumbnails visible/opaque/displayed span by modifying anything in the slideshow visible/opaque/displayed span.

Below is my code, including some of the function variants I tried, which are marked under the section Experimental Javascript. All the code until that section works well. I don't understand why the "experimental" code doesn't work, though. Does it conflict with the other functions, or is it over-ridden by them? If so, how should I modify it to get it to do all I want it to?

HTML:

```
   <span class="wrapper-focuser" id="slideshow">
        <span class="scrolling-wrapper">
            <span class="prev-card" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
            </span>
            <span class="next-card" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">
            </span>
            <span class="all-cards" onclick="allDivs()">
            </span>
            <div id="images">
                <div class="card slide one">
                      <img class="picture" onclick="allDivs()" src="img/Picture1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card slide two" onclick="allDivs()">
                      <img class="picture" src="img/Picture2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card slide three">
                      <img class="picture" onclick="allDivs()" src="img/Picture3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="thumbnails is-visible" id="gallery">
        <span class="scrolling-wrapper">
          <div id="small">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="allDivs(); plusDivs(+0); divDisp(1);" src="img/Picture1.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="allDivs(); plusDivs(+1); divDisp(2);" src="img/Picture2.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="allDivs(); plusDivs(+2); divDisp(3);" src="img/Picture3.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </span>
    </span>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper-focuser {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}


.scrolling-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.no-cursor {
    cursor: none;
}

.card { 
  height: auto; 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: url("/img/all.png"), auto;
}

.prev-card {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.prev-card:hover {
    cursor: url("/img/prev.png"), auto;
}

.next-card {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.next-card:hover {
    cursor: url("/img/next.png"), auto;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.all-cards {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.all-cards:hover {
    cursor: url("/img/all.png"), auto;
}

.thumbnails {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.thumbnail {
    padding: 10px; 
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.picture {
    position: relative;
}

.is-discernable {
        opacity: 1;
    }

.is-visible {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = "0";
        y[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
    y[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1"; 
}


function allDivs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("slideshow");
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery");
    var z = document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling-wrapper");
    if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
        x.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
        y.classList.toggle('is-visible');
        z.classList.toggle('no-cursor');
    } else {
        x.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
        y.classList.toggle('is-visible');
        z.classList.toggle('no-cursor');
    }
}
```

Experimental Javascript:

```
var pictureIndex = 1;
transpireDivs(pictureIndex);

function divDisp(n) {
    transpireDivs(pictureIndex += n);
}

function transpireDivs(n) {
    var x = n;
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
    var l = document.getElementsByClassName("two");
    var m = document.getElementsByClassName("three");
    if (x == 1) {
        k.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
    } else if (x == 2) {
        l.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
    } else if (x == 3) {
        m.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
    }    
}
```

I tried many other functions, and none of them worked. It's like the connexion between the wrapper and the gallery divs is short-circuited somehow, or like any new functions are over-ridden by one that I already wrote. I want to understand why that is, and some alternative solutions, such as creating two pages for the two divs that are linked by click-events, or structuring the slideshow in a different way.

Thank you all for your attention on this rather long code, and I hope my question helps others who may have a similar problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved your problem by resolving the errors the code gave in the browser console.

1. I added a listener that only executes `showDivs(slideIndex)` when the browser is done loading the page. Otherwise `x` and `y` will be empty at the first call, which makes that `x[slideIndex-1]` won't exist.
2. `z.classList.toggle('no-cursor');` gave an error because `z` is a list of elements, not an element.

   You need to loop over the elements: `for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {z[i].classList.toggle('no-cursor');}`
3. This did not give an error, but changing `showDivs(slideIndex += n);`  to `showDivs(slideIndex = n)` makes sure the right slide gets shown.

This is the replaced gallery:

```
 <span class="thumbnails is-visible" id="gallery">
        <span class="scrolling-wrapper">
          <div id="small">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="showDivFix(1);" src="img/Picture1.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="showDivFix(2);" src="img/Picture2.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="thumbnail" onclick="showDivFix(3);" src="img/Picture3.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </span>
    </span>
```

And the code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    showDivs(slideIndex);
});

function showDivFix(n) {
    allDivs();
    plusDivs(n);
    //divDisp(n);
}

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = "0";
        y[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
    y[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1"; 
}


function allDivs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("slideshow");
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery");
    var z = document.getElementsByClassName("scrolling-wrapper");
    x.classList.toggle('is-discernable');
    y.classList.toggle('is-visible');
    for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        z[i].classList.toggle('no-cursor');
    }
}
```

Good luck finishing your gallery/slider!

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a warm welcome with such a helpful answer, Thor! Just a slight tweak to the code you corrected helped me do everything I wanted. Since putting +=n allows images to scroll back and forth in slideshow-mode, whereas =n allows the clicked thumbnail in gallery-mode to start the slideshow-mode with the right image, I created two functions for each like so :                 function showDivFix(n) {
    allDivs();
    altDivs(n);
}

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function altDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
} . Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear you fixed it. Consider marking the answer as accepted. Since it was my first answer, that'll give me the ability to upvote posts. I desperately need to thank some people here :)